# Error when attempting to compile clojurescript

Tags: java, maven, clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to get clojurescript to compile but for some reason I'm running into a 'get_file_name' error. Has anyone come across this?

```
~/cosmos/cljs-todo
❯ lein cljsbuild auto
Compiling ClojureScript.
Retrieving prismatic/dommy/0.1.1/dommy-0.1.1.pom from clojars
Retrieving crate/crate/0.2.3/crate-0.2.3.pom from clojars
Retrieving prismatic/cljs-test/0.0.5/cljs-test-0.0.5.pom from clojars
Retrieving org/clojure/clojurescript/0.0-1934/clojurescript-0.0-1934.pom from central
Retrieving org/clojure/clojurescript/0.0-1934/clojurescript-0.0-1934.jar from central
Retrieving org/clojure/tools.reader/0.7.9/tools.reader-0.7.9.jar from central
Retrieving crate/crate/0.2.3/crate-0.2.3.jar from clojars
Retrieving prismatic/cljs-test/0.0.5/cljs-test-0.0.5.jar from clojars
Retrieving prismatic/dommy/0.1.1/dommy-0.1.1.jar from clojars
Reflection warning, clojure/tools/reader/reader_types.clj:34:1 - reference to field get_file_name can't be resolved.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define method not in interfaces: get_file_name, compiling:(clojure/tools/reader/reader_types.clj:107:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6567)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5708)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$LetExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:6009)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6560)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6322)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$BodyExpr$Parser.parse(Compiler.java:5708)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnMethod.parse(Compiler.java:5139)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$FnExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3751)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6558)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6361)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6616)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.tools.reader$eval125$loading__4910__auto____126.invoke(reader.clj:9)
    at clojure.tools.reader$eval125.invoke(reader.clj:9)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:482)
    at cljs.compiler$eval119$loading__4910__auto____120.invoke(compiler.clj:11)
    at cljs.compiler$eval119.invoke(compiler.clj:11)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
    at cljs.closure$eval111$loading__4910__auto____112.invoke(closure.clj:9)
    at cljs.closure$eval111.invoke(closure.clj:9)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:621)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5507)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at cljsbuild.compiler$eval9$loading__4910__auto____10.invoke(compiler.clj:1)
    at cljsbuild.compiler$eval9.invoke(compiler.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:370)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:361)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:440)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:411)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5018.invoke(core.clj:5530)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5529)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5336)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__4967.invoke(core.clj:5375)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5374)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5413)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5496)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at user$eval5.invoke(form-init5747593974752525212.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6619)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6608)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7064)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7020)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:294)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:299)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invoke(main.clj:327)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:362)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't define method not in interfaces: get_file_name
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceMethod.parse(Compiler.java:7911)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceExpr.build(Compiler.java:7471)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler$NewInstanceExpr$DeftypeParser.parse(Compiler.java:7352)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6560)
    ... 134 more
Subprocess failed
```

Comment: Can you add details about versions you are using on?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a version conflict. For example, you are using an old(er) versions for:

- `[crate "0.2.3"]`, the current one is `"0.2.4"`
- `[org.clojure/tools.reader "0.7.9"]`, the current one is `"0.7.10"`
- `[org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1934"]`, the current one is `"0.0-2030"`
- ...

As your question stands at the moment (with no edits), it does not have enough details of what you are trying to do with what versions, but here is an example of a working, current `project.clj` that uses all the ClojureScript goodness with all the versions aligned:

```
(defproject xyz "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "xyz is such and such"
  :url "https://github.com/tolitius/xyz"

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [compojure "1.1.6"]
                 [hiccup "1.0.4"]
                 [crate "0.2.4"]
                 [jayq "2.5.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2030"]]

  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.8"]
            [lein-cljsbuild "1.0.0-alpha2"]]

  :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]

  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{:source-paths ["src"]
              :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/xyz.js"
                         :optimizations :whitespace
                         :pretty-print true
                         :source-map "resources/public/js/xyz.js.map"
                         }}]}

  :ring {:handler auqlue.handler/app}

  :profiles
    {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                          [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}})
```

In case you are getting up to speed with a new ClojureScript project, check out David Nolen's [mies](https://github.com/swannodette/mies)

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being in my lein profile.

I was pulling in [org.clojure/core.typed "0.2.4"] for some odd reason I don't remember. After I removed that dependency it finally worked.